# Sign in problem as a teacher and as a student

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make an app for college purpose where students and teachers sign in and use the functionality.  But i don't want any student to sign in as a teacher. There will be different some different functionality for teachers and different for students so i don't want any student to sign in as a teacher.

Is this possible to achieve? How can i avoid this problem in my app?

Comment: This kind of validation should happen on the back-end. There is no way for you to prevent this on the mobile side.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes in my mind is that You can add a column of role in Your user database and set valus of T (for teacher) or S (for student) after it completes the necessary check and if the user that trying to login is actually a teacher or a student, but that is one of the steps you need to do for your application. There are way more things need to be done to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem with the current 'sign in' process, which brings you to this concern?

The users are signing in, this usually means there is some form of authentication. Having a form of authentication should rectify that problem for the most part.

You can add an extra field to the authentication process if the user selects that they wish to be signed in as a teacher, requiring a portion of their identification number (in addition to the regular username and password).

Answer (score 0):

This kind of validation should happen on the back-end. There is no way for you to prevent this on the mobile (or any front-end) side.

I suggest trying to find an experienced back-end engineer and look through all the possible cases where security is important (like querying for teacher-only information).

After all, I can just run the application through a proxy, see what `URL`s are being called, then call those same `URL`s from the command line.